# Google Maps Module Not Found On react-native-streetview

Tags: ios, react-native, google-street-view, react-native-maps

How to produce :

1. npm install react-native-streetview
2. Install GoogleMaps iOS SDK manually
3. react-native link
4. Build

And then comes error like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3SBG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` in AppDelegate.m file and add this also

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

{`[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR-API-KEY-HERE"];`
And also provide the path of your *GoogleMaps iOS SDK* in Framework Search Path

Comment: I've do that but that error still appear. Any other solution?